# CSS Text align: center ignored even with !important specified

Tags: html, css

I have the following [site here](http://bit.ly/1rkBTfZ) that is using CSS for the Nav element.  I have defined the class as the following but it is making the menu text flush left even though I specified !important?

```
#nav {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
    clear: both;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', arial, serif!important; 

height: 30px;
width: 100%;
text-align:center;
padding-top: 3px;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
position: relative;
background-color: #BD8D2B;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the removing the float left on the menu `<ul>` and adding `margin:0 auto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to float your UL element to the left, only the LI's. Floating the UL to the left is pushing that block of content to the left. Removing the float and applying a margin: auto to the left and right of your element will center it in modern browsers.

```
#nav ul {
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  width: 950px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As j08691 suggested you should remove the `float:left;` from the ul element and adding `margin:0 auto;` to center the menu.

```
#nav ul { 
  float:none; 
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```